# problem with spring mvc application doesnt work 404 error ressource not found

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

so i was trying to debug an imported application spring mvc, but there is a problem that prevent my application to start and it gives me error 404 The requested resource is not available.

[image]

[enter link description here][2]

here's web.xml
[2]: https://codeshare.io/5X3ppn

Comment: Please don't share code as images, those are unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry but i wanted to share the structure in the image not the code if you want me to sdhow you a specific one i can share it in codeshare

Comment: You added the `web.xml` as an image, however it is XML and therefor it is code which should be treated as such.

Comment: here is the code of web.xml https://codeshare.io/5X3ppn

Comment: Again don't post it as images post it as code as part of your question. As stated it is XML and thus code and should be treated as such. Next to that don't let people follow links to get a full understanding. All the information should be in your question.

Comment: i can give you the project in github if you're willing to give me the solution to solve this

Comment: I'm not going to checkout a github project or do your work for you unless you are paying me to do so. So please add all relevant information to the question so people can see it. Also please clarify is this an existing working application or doesn't it work alltogher? ANd please add it to the question, not as images, just add text and not as comments either.

Comment: don't check it out and please if you don't have a solution or any clue about it don't be rude that won't get you anywhere ! and my question is not clear as much as for me thats why im here and i don't want to post the code directly because its my business after all !
thanks
ps : its an existing working app

Comment: The only thing I did was ask for additional information AND that you add it to your question. Your question contains far too little information to solve this. Judging from what you added in the comments to the answer this isn't a working application or you already changed things. BUt one last time please add your config and web.xml and stacktrace to your question. as code, not as links, not as comments as code.

Comment: What was the requested resource?

Answer (score 0):

Check your studentManagement-servlet.xml file may be you have defined XML-based configuration, by using mvc:resources element and there is no resources folder. For example:

```
<!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

Comment: here's my studentManagement-servlet.xml file

https://codeshare.io/aJXAvq

Comment: In your line number 14 and 20 there is a beans tag. I think it should not be there as your're already in beans tag

Comment: yes indeed ive deleted it but still i got the same issue 404